# How to use update promise?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this functions here

```
      return db.ref("/data/" + item.ID).update({
        imageURI: item.imageURI,
        name: item.name,
        expire: item.expire,
        type: item.type,
      })
    };
```

and I am wondering how can I get a return Promise out of this and use the new item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain other functions to the update function:

```js
db.ref("/data/" + item.ID).update({
  imageURI: item.imageURI,
  name: item.name,
  expire: item.expire,
  type: item.type,
}).then(function() {
  console.log('success')
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Well this is the problem .. where/how do I get the updated item ??

Comment: you don't. Updating it means you know what it'll be

Answer (score 0):

Updating a value doesn't return the item. Why should it ? You surely don't need firebase to the send you the whole object when you're updating only one field.

Then, you would have to set a listener : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Besides, updating it means you already have the updated object.